# Should I use one singleton for different purposes?

Tags: java, design-patterns, optimization, singleton, refactoring

Ok, stackoverflow. 
 I've got to use singleton for database and for internet-processing. Is it a good practice to use one singleton for these (and have a mess in my singleton class) or two different singletons (and duplicate some singleton code). 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious as to what duplicated code database and internet have in common.

Comment: Opinion-based, but in general see [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good approach to use the same class with two different purposes.
Each class should have a unique responsibility ([Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

If you need to duplicate some code between classes, consider refactoring and creating a superclass for both classes (if classes can be siblings), or use some kind of helper class to perform the common operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an enum say

```
    public ProcessManager{
     DB_PROCESS {    
                  public void process(){
                                ... specific code for db
                                commonCode();         
                                ..specific code for DB
                               }
                      }, 
     NETWORK_PROCESS{
                   public void process(){
                              ... specific code for network
                              commonCode();
                              ...specific code for network         
                               }
                     };

     public void process(){
     }

     public void commonCode(){

             ... common code
     }  
     }
```

How to call?

*ProcessManager.DB_PROCESS .process();
ProcessManager.NETWORK_PROCESS.process();*

Remember **enums are the best way to implement a singleton class (effective-java-2nd-edition)**